# Pylons Paster not reloading code

Tags: python, apache, pylons, paster

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Paste (Python) Web Server - Autoreload Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252885/paste-python-web-server-autoreload-problem)

I have a pylons app in development. I start the app with paster serve --reload --daemon development.ini.  I have apache in front of the app using ProxyPass. Since this site is in dev i want the code to reload when i change the source files. I thought --reload was supposed to reload the app on code change but that doesn't seem to be happening. Any ideas?

Comment: Try only `paster serve --reload development.ini`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think --daemon and --reload are compatible. --daemon is meant to really launch and run constantly. If you need to keep it running in the background and disconnect/leave the terminal, then background it or run it in a screen session instead.

```
paster serve --reload development.ini &
```